# Scrolling to element inside scrollable container div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to elements (.list-view-items) inside the following container

```
<div id='list-view'>
  <ul>
    <li class='list-view-item'>
      ...
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>

#list-view {
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted @gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#list-view ul {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

I have tried manually scrolling in chrome devtools with

```
$('#list-view ul').scrollTop = 1000
```

But nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using jQuery, scrollTop is a method, so you need to set the value as a parameter

`$('#list-view ul').scrollTop(1000)`

Comment: If it solved your problem, you might want to consider marking this answer as correct =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS, adding a height to both elements, and adding `overflow:scroll` to the parent element.

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ftpzeby9/).